# Mo pub + iAds in iPhone landscape game

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, mopub

Now I got one requirement to use MoPub+iAds in iPhone game.

I used mo pub sdk and initialized view like this

```
MPAdView *moPubAdView =  [[MPAdView alloc] initWithAdUnitId:MOPUB_ADS_ACCOUNT_ID size:MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE];
```

But this displays 320x50 in size. How to enable iAd for this view? Now it is displaying only mo pub ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the slim iAd banner you have to pass the correct CGSize in the size parameter. In this case CGSizeMake(480, 32).
To enable iAds for your App go to itunesconnect.apple.com and add your app with your bundle ID. After that find the Button which says iAd Network Settings and enable iAds.

The slim lanscape is rare. Your fillrate will be low. I recommend to use MMA Banner (320, 50) even for landscape orientation. Do this by using this function:

```
[mpAdView lockNativeAdsToOrientation:MPNativeAdOrientationPortrait];
```

Also be sure to import the iAd Adapter. Its by default included.

Comment: thanks for the reply, already added MPIAdAdapter.h in Xcode, but not added any code to specify to enable iAds. Now getting mo-pub ads some time and some time it logs no ads. Why not iAds coming all other time? (if no mo pub ads r there )

Comment: Did you enable iAd for your app in the MoPub dashboard? Try to disable all other networks and the marketplace and check, if you getting iAds. There is also a test ad button in MoPub where you can see which network should deliver an ad.